# asp.net core modelstate.exception jsonreaderexception differentiate unsupported media type from invalid property type

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

Lets assume POST action method that expects json parameter like:

```
{
t:25
}
```

**Case 1)** - if we send something like

```
{
t:
```

then action should return **415 - Unsupported Media Type** as parser won't be able to understand json (as its incomplete)

**Case 2)** - if we sent something like

```
{
t:'124'
}
```

so, sending string for property that is defined as int (in expected action model), we should return **422 - Unprocessable Entity** as its a validation problem.

But, for both cases we get the same ModelState.Exception of type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException.

Question is, how to distinguish from those two cases?

Comment: Isn't double-quote (") the common enclosing character for json?

Comment: thats anothertopic. the question is the same regardless of quoting style you use.